# Facebook share dialog posting not working from ios device

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Hi,
 I am using new fbsdk. Implemented this in my ios project. And I can post fbsdksharedialog to my fb page from simulator. But its not woring with the device. I am using developer profile. All the setting are done as per described in developers.facebook.com. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show code example?

Comment: [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                  withContent:content
                                     delegate:nil];

Comment: Also i have used
FBSDKLoginManager
FBSDKGraphRequest to fetch data

after that called FBSDKShareDialog